# Unity. Изменение параметров скрипта на объекте

Tags: c#, unity3d

Делаю простенькую аркаду на unity, у меня на уровне должны вылетать в персонажа сложные фигуры, которые двигаются по определенной задумке.

```
 Instantiate(Revolve_double, new Vector3(30, height, 0), Quaternion.identity);

 MoveAndDie game_speed = Revolve_double.gameObject.GetComponent<MoveAndDie>(); //скорость уровня
 game_speed.X = Speed;

 Rotation rotationObj = Revolve_double.gameObject.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.GetComponent<Rotation>(); //скорость вращения 
 rotationObj.rotation = Random.Range(0, 70);

 foreach (Transform child in Revolve_double.gameObject.transform.GetChild(0))
 {
       Rotation rotationChild = child.gameObject.GetComponent<Rotation>(); //вращение ребенка для красоты
       rotationChild.rotation = Random.Range(-15, 40);

       child.localPosition = new Vector3(Random.Range(0,10), Random.Range(0, 10), 0); //позиция ребенка
 }
```

И тут я начал замечать баги, связанные с тем, что у меня все префабы стоят с нулевыми настройками (все значения скриптов и позиция обьектов на нуле). Так вот, мой скрипт меняет значения самих префабов, а не только что созданных обьектов. Как мне менять значения конкретного обьекта, только что созданного функцией `Instantiate()` ?

Скрипт `MoveAndDie` влияет на скорость обьекта, который летит в игрока, а скрипт `Rotation` вращает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Посмотрите внимательней на документацию по методу [Instantiate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html). У этого объекта есть возвращаемое значение - тот объект, который был создан. В своем коде вы никак не взаимодействуете с объектом, который создаете, так как не сохраняете возвращаемое значение метода `Instantiate`. Все свои модификации вы проводите только с исходным префабом.

Предположим, что ваша переменная `Revolve_double` это `GameObject`. Вы можете исправить код создания объекта следующим образом:

```
var revolveInstance = (GameObject)Instantiate(Revolve_double,
                                              new Vector3(30, height, 0),
                                              Quaternion.identity);
```

И далее модифицировать уже свойства (параметры) созданного вами объекта, который будет храниться в переменной `revolveInstance`.

Чтобы получше разобраться в теме работы с префабами и их инстанциирование, можете глянуть [официальный туториал на эту тему](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InstantiatingPrefabs.html). Тутор полностью на английском, но в нем есть полезные вам примеры кода.